# How to implement custom if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am making one custom script language in textbox.

For example: 
`<NAME1>`, `<NAME2>` or `<FAM>` and when executing it the tags are transform into the data that is coming from file, database or user input from fields.

In the given example the result is:

```
Elliot, John or Gleave.
```

This is good for now. I come to the conclusion that I need if statement.

Here is some example:

```
<IF NAME1="George">
<DoStuff>
<ENDIF>
```

The methods that I am using are finding indexes from the string and substringing them.
Can you give me some ideas or guidance how to make the custom if statement?

**EDIT:** I managed to make a method for doing what I want. So here I am sharing it if someone wants to edit, advice or etc. Please advise me.

```
public static string ReplaceIfStatement(string script, CResultData resultData)
{
    string workingScript = script;
    string manipulatedScript = workingScript.Clone() as string; // storing the script in temp variable for further checks

    workingScript = CStringFunctions.ReplaceAll(workingScript, "\r", string.Empty); // ReplaceAll uses the string.Replace() method
    workingScript = CStringFunctions.ReplaceAll(workingScript, "\t", string.Empty);

    string ifStartFieldName = "<IF ";
    string ifEndFieldName = "<ENDIF>";

    workingScript = CStringFunctions.ReplaceAll(workingScript, "<IF\n", ifStartFieldName);

    bool repeat = true;

    while (repeat)
    {
        int ifStartIndexOpenTag = workingScript.IndexOf(ifStartFieldName);
        int ifEndIndexOpenTag = workingScript.IndexOf(ifEndFieldName);

        if (ifStartIndexOpenTag != -1 
            || ifEndIndexOpenTag != -1)
        {
            int ifStartIndexCloseTag = CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(
                workingScript,
                ">",
                ifStartIndexOpenTag + ifStartFieldName.Length + 1); //IndexOfString() uses the IndexOf()

            int ifEndIndexCloseTag = CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(
                workingScript,
                ">",
                ifEndIndexOpenTag + ifStartFieldName.Length + 1);

            if (ifStartIndexCloseTag != -1)
            {
                string ifStatement = CStringFunctions.SubstrString(
                    workingScript,
                    ifStartIndexOpenTag + ifStartFieldName.Length,
                    ifStartIndexCloseTag - (ifStartIndexOpenTag + ifStartFieldName.Length));

                ifStatement = CStringFunctions.ReplaceAll(ifStatement, " ", string.Empty);

                string rightSideIfStatement = CStringFunctions.SubstrString(
                    ifStatement,
                    1,
                    CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(ifStatement, "=") - 1);

                string leftSideIfStatement = CStringFunctions.SubstrString(
                    ifStatement,
                    CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(ifStatement, "=") + 1,
                    CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(ifStatement, ")")
                    - CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(ifStatement, "=") - 1);

                CResultData ifResultData = resultData.Clone(); // here is the class containing all props, ex: NAME1, NAME2 or FAM

                foreach (PropertyInfo property in ifResultData.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (rightSideIfStatement == property.Name.ToUpper()
                        && leftSideIfStatement == (string)property.GetValue(ifResultData, null)) // In this statement compare the property name in the <IF> and the <IF (statement)> 
                    {
                        //if the compare is true i remove the <IF (statement)> and the <ENDIF> from the script
                        manipulatedScript = CStringFunctions.ReplaceStringAtPosition(
                            workingScript,
                            ifStartIndexOpenTag,
                            ifStartIndexCloseTag + 1,
                            string.Empty);

                        ifEndIndexOpenTag = CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(manipulatedScript, ifEndFieldName);
                        ifEndIndexCloseTag = CStringFunctions.IndexOfString(
                            manipulatedScript,
                            ">",
                            ifEndIndexOpenTag + ifStartFieldName.Length + 1);

                        manipulatedScript = CStringFunctions.ReplaceStringAtPosition(
                            manipulatedScript,
                            ifEndIndexOpenTag,
                            ifEndIndexCloseTag + 1,
                            string.Empty);

                        workingScript = manipulatedScript;

                        return workingScript;
                    }
                }

                if (manipulatedScript != null && manipulatedScript.Length == workingScript.Length) // When the IF statement is false
                //here I compare the parameter script with the temp script if there are changes to remove from the script begging from <IF (statement)> to <ENDIF>
                {
                    manipulatedScript = CStringFunctions.ReplaceStringAtPosition(
                        workingScript,
                        ifStartIndexOpenTag,
                        ifEndIndexCloseTag + 1,
                        string.Empty);

                    workingScript = manipulatedScript;

                    return workingScript;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                repeat = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            repeat = false;
        }
    }

    workingScript = manipulatedScript;

    return workingScript;
}
```

Comment: what you mean by `custom if statement`. what the difference with usual c# `if` statement?

Comment: In the given example I explain it what I want. <IF (boolean expression)> <DoStuff> <ENDIF>.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I understand you're trying to implement a scripting language, but it's still hard to understand what exactly you need help with.

Comment: If you are building a scripting language, ANTLR might be of help, although I find it quite complex.

Comment: I made some example implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to write a custom script language in the style of the markup you provided above, you might as well make it XML-compliant.

[See this example of parsing XML.](http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/08/parsing-xml-in-c-a-quick-working-sample/)

Assuming the use of XML and the syntax described above,

```
var document = new XMLDocument();
document.Load(xmlFilePath);

var documentNodes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("path/from/root/to/stuff/of/interest");

foreach (var node in documentNodes)
{
    var name1NodeValue = node.SelectSingleNode("NAME1").InnerText;
    var ifNode = node.SelectSingleNode("IF");
    if (ifNode.Attributes["NAME1"].Value.Equals(name1NodeValue) {
        //Look for the node of interest. I just hard-coded doStuff for the sake of brevity.
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Not a perfect example but should be good enough to get you going.